# Can php session_set_cookie_params and setcookie be used in different instances or does 1 override the other

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to setup a cookie, but need to have 2 for 2 different things inside 1 script. What is the best method of doing this?

Fine my code below -

`session_name('tzLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(10*365*24*60*60);
session_start();`

I am needing to use php setcookie as well.
Will 1 cookie method override the other, will they have problems between each other.

Comment: Each cookie can have different options. But this is a session. And it's pretty uncommon to have two of them. Have you tried it out? What does your browsers cookie store receive?

Comment: Ok thanks, but so my website utilizes get/post methods. Can that cookie be used on a different URL with different POST methods?
For example - http://lit.life/gallry/aidan/post.php?profile=image.png&prof=&title=&rep=1&text_post=+++++++%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%09

http://lit.life/gallry/aidan/post.php?profile=image.png&prof=&title=asdf&rep=1&text_post=+++++++%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%09

Comment: Cookies accompany each request to the same domain regardless of HTTP method. Question, again: why *two* **sessions**?